# itextsharp: How to find the fill color of a rectangle

Tags: c#, itext

I follow ItextSharp example for getting a graphical structure, to get the rectangle coordinates, using code:

```
class VectorGraphicsListener : IExtRenderListener
{
public void ModifyPath(PathConstructionRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
    if (renderInfo.Operation == PathConstructionRenderInfo.RECT)
    {
        float x = renderInfo.SegmentData[0];
        float y = renderInfo.SegmentData[1];
        float w = renderInfo.SegmentData[2];
        float h = renderInfo.SegmentData[3];  
...
```

I tried the renderInfo.GetFillColor();
but there is no such a method.

I want to get additional rectangle properties :
like rectangle fill color,( some analog to DIV style="background: blue; border:black;" tag in html)
how I get it ?

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to use reflection you access the graphics state at the time of rendering the path.

Answer (score 1):

`TextRenderInfo` has the method you are looking for for `PathConstructionRenderInfo` does not.

Where did you get the example from? You are probably using a different version than the version documentation used.

This article explains what you need to do but it provides Java source code which should be pretty easy to port to C#: http://techqa.info/programming/question/41728853/how-to-extract-the-color-of-a-rectangle-in-a-pdf,-with-itext

To summarize the relevant portions, it uses `GraphicsState` to get the fill color. To achieve this you will need parse all of the PDF's content with a `PdfReaderContentParser` passing a derived `ExtRenderListener` to the `processContent` method as follows (taken from the Java Code above):

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(resource);
ExtRenderListener extRenderListener = new ExtRenderListener();
for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); page++)
{
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(pdfReader);
    parser.processContent(page, extRenderListener);

}
```

The ExtRenderListener will need to override renderPath:

```
public override Path renderPath(PathPaintingRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
    Field gsField = PathPaintingRenderInfo.class.getDeclaredField("gs");
    gsField.setAccessible(true);
    GraphicsState graphicsState = (GraphicsState) gsField.get(renderInfo);
    if ((renderInfo.getOperation() & PathPaintingRenderInfo.FILL) != 0)
    {
        var fillColor = graphicsState.getFillColor();
        bool filledRect= false;
        for (PathConstructionRenderInfo pathConstructionRenderInfo in pathInfos) 
        {
            if(pathConstructionRenderInfo.getOperation()==PathConstructionRenderInfo.RECT)
            {
                filledRect=true;
                break;
            }
            if (filledRect && fillColor!=null)
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}",
                fillColor.getRed(), fillColor.getGreen(), fillColor.getBlue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That link may answer the question but please add the pivotal parts to your answer.

Comment: From the question, it sounded like there was already sample code to go from. In any case, I summarized the relevant portions of the code.

Comment: In my eyes the most relevant part is that the colour is retrieved from the graphics state which is retrieved via  reflection as can be seen in your `renderPath` override.

Comment: Allexander ,you right,it's from Java link, I tried to implement the GraphicsState (as mkl mentioned) with no success, I'll follow your C# code example, to test .

Comment: to extract the coordinates I get now from :  if(pathConstructionRenderInfo.getOperation()==PathConstructionRenderInfo.RECT)
            { float x = renderInfo.SegmentData[0];... } ?

Comment: on the beginning got reference error on ExtRenderListener tried : 
   itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ExtRenderListener; , with no success, can you give full class code demo ?

Comment: @Allexander, actually you gave .java code, I checked your code more and in C# .Net, there are non declared field also and IExtRenderListener interface (not an Object), can you adjust your code for .Net ?, the best if you can give a link to whole class code example, included all references.

Comment: As stated, `TextRenderInfo` contains the `GetFillColor()` method. It returns it from the `GraphicsState` object passed to it. https://github.com/kusl/itextsharp/blob/master/tags/iTextSharp_5_4_5/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/TextRenderInfo.cs `ExtRenderListener();` is a custom class. The Java code this custom class to parse the objects in the document. You will need to write your own implementation of `ExtRenderListener();`

Comment: Field in .Net, from your code example above, how I declare the :Field gsField = PathPaintingRenderInfo.class.getDeclaredField("gs"); ? I got error, just help me the field reference in C#, and I can advance. the link you gave,is not about rectangle fillColor. can other persons enter to discussion , to solve this issue ?

Comment: That code is Java. You need to write your own code. Your code will need to use the appropriate .net classes such as TextRenderInfo and not PathPaintingRenderInfo which exists in Java.

Comment: @Alexander, I have been told for rectangle extract fillColor, not to use TextRenderInfo, now you write the opposite, can somebody help with GraphicsState , and field in .Net ?

Comment: Where is the PDF in question?

Comment: @alexander Where is your answer ?

Comment: I asked where the PDF is? You were told not use it but have you tried it? There are examples on Stack overflow on how to get text from a rectangle use TextRenderInfo. It has the method to get the fill color.

Comment: @alexander ,from beginning we deal just on rectangle graphic shape , no text, look at the header question, I think you are not familier with C# code for itextSharp, you just copy some Java link, in this point I want to end this discussion

Comment: I am not getting into a pissing match with you. I asked for the actual PDF. I informed you that you need to write your own code for this. The document content is going to be unique and the objects in it need to be parsed. I pointed to the Java code as an example while pointing out the classes and methods that need to be used with the C# DLL. I see no effort on your behalf. Instead attacks on me and you repeatedly asking for the code. I am certainly familiar with it, including use it to create on the fly PDFs, perform mail merges for mailings to millions, form submission confirmations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [page Alexander in his answer posted a link to](http://techqa.info/programming/question/41728853/how-to-extract-the-color-of-a-rectangle-in-a-pdf,-with-itext) is a copy of an [earlier answer by me here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41751396/1729265).

Thus, I simply ported the code from that answer (which was using iText / Java) to iTextSharp / C#:

#### The custom `IExtRenderListener` implementation

```
class ExtRenderListener : IExtRenderListener
{
    public void BeginTextBlock() { }
    public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) { }
    public void EndTextBlock() { }
    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) { }

    public void ModifyPath(PathConstructionRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        pathInfos.Add(renderInfo);
    }

    public iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.Path RenderPath(PathPaintingRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        GraphicsState graphicsState = getGraphicsState(renderInfo);
        Matrix ctm = graphicsState.GetCtm();

        if ((renderInfo.Operation & PathPaintingRenderInfo.FILL) != 0)
        {
            Console.Write("FILL ({0}) ", toString(graphicsState.FillColor));
            if ((renderInfo.Operation & PathPaintingRenderInfo.STROKE) != 0)
                Console.Write("and ");
        }
        if ((renderInfo.Operation & PathPaintingRenderInfo.STROKE) != 0)
        {
            Console.Write("STROKE ({0}) ", toString(graphicsState.StrokeColor));
        }

        Console.Write("the path ");

        foreach (PathConstructionRenderInfo pathConstructionRenderInfo in pathInfos)
        {
            switch (pathConstructionRenderInfo.Operation)
            {
                case PathConstructionRenderInfo.MOVETO:
                    Console.Write("move to {0} ", toString(transform(ctm, pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData)));
                    break;
                case PathConstructionRenderInfo.CLOSE:
                    Console.Write("close {0} ", toString(transform(ctm, pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData)));
                    break;
                case PathConstructionRenderInfo.CURVE_123:
                    Console.Write("curve123 {0} ", toString(transform(ctm, pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData)));
                    break;
                case PathConstructionRenderInfo.CURVE_13:
                    Console.Write("curve13 {0} ", toString(transform(ctm, pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData)));
                    break;
                case PathConstructionRenderInfo.CURVE_23:
                    Console.Write("curve23 {0} ", toString(transform(ctm, pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData)));
                    break;
                case PathConstructionRenderInfo.LINETO:
                    Console.Write("line to {0} ", toString(transform(ctm, pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData)));
                    break;
                case PathConstructionRenderInfo.RECT:
                    Console.Write("rectangle {0} ", toString(transform(ctm, expandRectangleCoordinates(pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData))));
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        pathInfos.Clear();
        return null;
    }

    String toString(IList<float> coordinates)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.Append("[ ");
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Count; i++)
        {
            result.Append(coordinates[i]);
            result.Append(' ');
        }
        result.Append(']');
        return result.ToString();
    }

    List<float> transform(Matrix ctm, IList<float> coordinates)
    {
        List<float> result = new List<float>();
        for (int i = 0; i + 1 < coordinates.Count; i += 2)
        {
            Vector vector = new Vector(coordinates[i], coordinates[i + 1], 1);
            vector = vector.Cross(ctm);
            result.Add(vector[Vector.I1]);
            result.Add(vector[Vector.I2]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    List<float> expandRectangleCoordinates(IList<float> rectangle)
    {
        if (rectangle.Count < 4)
            return new List<float>();
        return new List<float>
        {
                rectangle[0], rectangle[1],
                rectangle[0] + rectangle[2], rectangle[1],
                rectangle[0] + rectangle[2], rectangle[1] + rectangle[3],
                rectangle[0], rectangle[1] + rectangle[3]
        };
    }

    String toString(BaseColor baseColor)
    {
        if (baseColor == null)
            return "DEFAULT";
        return String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", baseColor.R, baseColor.G, baseColor.B);
    }

    GraphicsState getGraphicsState(PathPaintingRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo gsField = typeof(PathPaintingRenderInfo).GetField("gs", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        return (GraphicsState) gsField.GetValue(renderInfo);
    }

    public void ClipPath(int rule)
    {
    }

    List<PathConstructionRenderInfo> pathInfos = new List<PathConstructionRenderInfo>();
}
```

The required reflection required to retrieve the `GraphicsState` takes place in the method `getGraphicsState`.

#### Using the `ExtRenderListener` class

```
using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader([FILE TO PARSE]))
{
    IExtRenderListener extRenderListener = new ExtRenderListener();
    // Loop through each page of the document
    for (var page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
    {
        Console.Write("\nPage {0}\n====\n", page);
        PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(pdfReader);
        parser.ProcessContent(page, extRenderListener);
    }
}
```

#### Output

For the PDF that former question was about, this code returns

```
Page 1
====
STROKE (0,0,0) the path rectangle [ 88,3 693,69 227,77 693,69 227,77 788 88,3 788 ] 
STROKE (0,0,0) the path rectangle [ 227,77 693,69 367,24 693,69 367,24 788 227,77 788 ] 
STROKE (0,0,0) the path rectangle [ 367,23 693,69 506,7 693,69 506,7 788 367,23 788 ] 
FILL (255,0,0) the path rectangle [ 229,77 695,69 365,37 695,69 365,37 786,09 229,77 786,09 ] 
STROKE (DEFAULT) the path move to [ 228 810 ] line to [ 338 810 ]
```

(As you can observe in the coordinate outputs, my current locale uses a comma as decimal separator...)

Comment: thanks for C# answer, that explains the reflaction(which I am not familier) . I'll follow this example to my code. I also found your older C# example on getting textRenderer font, and fontsize.. that reminds your current approach. well, the C# syntax is different from Java,without your example, I could not get the solution

Comment: entering the RenderPath cycle, what command is the analog to javascript canvas : ctx.beginPath(); ?, the .ctx.Stroke() is actual Draw ,the last command after settings:MOVTTO,LINETO,CURVE...

Comment: I don't know what *javascript canvas : ctx.beginPath()* is for. In PDFs paths are started with an initial move-to, no extra starting instruction required.