# itextsharp : How do you find the fill and stroke color using ColorSpaceStroke and ColorSpaceFill?

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to use the solution provided by [another SFO link - itextsharp: How to find the fill color of a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867468/itextsharp-how-to-find-the-fill-color-of-a-rectangle)

I have implemented the interface **IExtRenderListener** as per the above article. Everything works fine , however for some of the vectors, I get a NULL value for **CurrentFillColor** and **CurrentStrokeColor**. In such situations, I find that the properties **ColorSpaceFill** and **ColorSpaceStroke** have some **non-NULL** values.

What is the prescribed approach in such situations?  (itextsharp 5.5.12)

Thanks,
Sau
[image: Value of GraphicState when Fill and Stroke are NULL]

Answer (score 0):

If you study ISO 32000, you'll discover that colors can be defined in different ways.

When iText shows a `StrokeColor` or a `FillColor` value different from `null`, you can tell if it's a gray color, an RGB color or a CMYK color depending on the size of the array.

However, sometimes you get a `ColorSpaceStroke` and `ColorSpaceFill` value instead of a color value that can be interpreted directly. In your case, the color is stored separately as a reusable resource with name `/Cs6`. You need to examine the resources in this PDF, and look for the color object by its name.

Comment: Thank you @Bruno. I was expecting that this color would defined as a resource. Do you have a sample code snippet in Java or C# which demonstrates how to read a value from the resources section?