# iTextSharp get reference to a graphic markup

Tags: vb.net, pdf, graphics, itext, markup

I have been researching for a couple of hours on how to do this but have hit a brick wall. I have a PDF file and one of the objects is a North arrow. It is a simple line graphic (I believe they are called Graphic Markups in Acrobat) that will denote which way is "up". I want to read that line graphic and determine its rotation. First step I took is to see if I could enumerate the contents of the PDF with this code:

```
Imports it = iTextSharp.text
Imports ip = iTextSharp.text.pdf

Dim pdfRdr As New ip.PdfReader("C:\city.pdf")
Dim page As ip.PdfDictionary = pdfRdr.GetPageN(1)
Dim objectReference As ip.PdfIndirectReference = CType(page.Get(ip.PdfName.CONTENTS), ip.PdfIndirectReference)
Dim stream As ip.PRStream = CType(ip.PdfReader.GetPdfObject(objectReference), ip.PRStream)
Dim streamBytes() As Byte = ip.PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(stream)
Dim tokenizer As New ip.PRTokeniser(New ip.RandomAccessFileOrArray(streamBytes))

'Loop through each PDf token
While tokenizer.NextToken
     Debug.Print("token of type={0} and value={1}", tokenizer.TokenType.ToString, tokenizer.StringValue)
End While
```

I do get some data back but am afraid I just don't understand how to decipher it.

```
token of type=OTHER and value=q
token of type=NUMBER and value=0.86275
token of type=NUMBER and value=0
token of type=NUMBER and value=0
token of type=NUMBER and value=0.86275
token of type=NUMBER and value=54
token of type=NUMBER and value=30
token of type=OTHER and value=cm
token of type=NAME and value=Fm0
token of type=OTHER and value=Do
token of type=OTHER and value=Q
token of type=OTHER and value=q
token of type=NUMBER and value=1
token of type=NUMBER and value=0
token of type=NUMBER and value=0
token of type=NUMBER and value=1
token of type=NUMBER and value=54
token of type=NUMBER and value=18
token of type=OTHER and value=cm
token of type=NAME and value=Fm1
token of type=OTHER and value=Do
token of type=OTHER and value=Q
```

I have skinnied down the PDF to show only the graphic that I am interested in.
[image]
[image]

test file is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dYFkvLMvznsx6sN-1GsNZVIBtDpgzwCU/view?usp=sharing

Am I going down the right path or is there a different way to get a reference to a graphic markup?

Comment: That's an application and it's commercial. I need to do this programatically for many PDFs and hopefully with iTextSharp. many thanks.

Comment: Please share the example pdf. Without it answering becomes guesswork.

Comment: Added a link to my Google Drive with the test file.

Comment: Ok, its not markup (which would imply a markup annotation), there merely are some vector graphics commands in the page content stream. This does definitively not match your original tokenizer output which referred to some XObjects, and considering the scales used there most likely some form XObjects... Thus: Is your sample PDF really representative?

Comment: I had to cut down all the sensitive data but the vector data is a copy/paste from the original. I have RUPS installed so could I analyze the structure for what I need?

Comment: I just applied your code to your example PDF. In the output I see multiple blocks `q {6 numbers} cm 0 0 m {2 numbers} l S Q`. These are instructions storing the graphics state, changing the current transformation matrix, moving to 0,0, adding a line to some coordinates, stroking the line, and restoring the graphics state. Your compass is made up of these lines. I'll write an answer later (tomorrow?)  processing these information in an easier manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In contrast to the initial impression, the north arrow is not in an annotation of the PDF but instead part of the regular page content. (@Jon created his answer under that initial impression.)*

*In the PDF shared by the OP, the arrow is part of the immediate page content. In the Adobe Acrobat screenshot shared by the OP, on the other hand, the arrow appears to be in a form XObject (which in turn would be referenced from the immediate page content).*

*The following approach should retrieve the vector graphics instructions for either case.*

You can retrieve the vector graphics instructions drawing the arrow using the iText parser framework.

Using a current iText 5.5.x, for example, you need to implement `IExtRenderListener` and use that implementation in a `PdfReaderContentParser` execution, e.g.:

```
Public Class VectorParser
    Implements IExtRenderListener

    Public Sub ModifyPath(renderInfo As PathConstructionRenderInfo) Implements IExtRenderListener.ModifyPath
        pathInfos.Add(renderInfo)
    End Sub

    Public Function RenderPath(renderInfo As PathPaintingRenderInfo) As parser.Path Implements IExtRenderListener.RenderPath
        Dim GraphicsState As GraphicsState = getGraphicsState(renderInfo)
        Dim ctm As Matrix = GraphicsState.GetCtm()

        If (Not (renderInfo.Operation And PathPaintingRenderInfo.FILL) = 0) Then
            Console.Write("FILL ({0}) ", ToString(GraphicsState.FillColor))
            If (Not (renderInfo.Operation And PathPaintingRenderInfo.STROKE) = 0) Then
                Console.Write("and ")
            End If
        End If

        If (Not (renderInfo.Operation And PathPaintingRenderInfo.STROKE) = 0) Then
            Console.Write("STROKE ({0}) ", ToString(GraphicsState.StrokeColor))
        End If

        Console.Write("the path ")

        For Each pathConstructionRenderInfo In pathInfos
            Select Case pathConstructionRenderInfo.Operation
                Case PathConstructionRenderInfo.MOVETO
                    Console.Write("move to {0} ", ToString(transform(ctm, pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData)))
                Case PathConstructionRenderInfo.CLOSE
                    Console.Write("close {0} ", ToString(transform(ctm, pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData)))
                Case PathConstructionRenderInfo.CURVE_123
                    Console.Write("curve123 {0} ", ToString(transform(ctm, pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData)))
                Case PathConstructionRenderInfo.CURVE_13
                    Console.Write("curve13 {0} ", ToString(transform(ctm, pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData)))
                Case PathConstructionRenderInfo.CURVE_23
                    Console.Write("curve23 {0} ", ToString(transform(ctm, pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData)))
                Case PathConstructionRenderInfo.LINETO
                    Console.Write("line to {0} ", ToString(transform(ctm, pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData)))
                Case PathConstructionRenderInfo.RECT
                    Console.Write("rectangle {0} ", ToString(transform(ctm, expandRectangleCoordinates(pathConstructionRenderInfo.SegmentData))))
            End Select
        Next

        Console.WriteLine()

        pathInfos.Clear()
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Sub ClipPath(rule As Integer) Implements IExtRenderListener.ClipPath
    End Sub

    Public Sub BeginTextBlock() Implements IRenderListener.BeginTextBlock
    End Sub

    Public Sub RenderText(renderInfo As TextRenderInfo) Implements IRenderListener.RenderText
    End Sub

    Public Sub EndTextBlock() Implements IRenderListener.EndTextBlock
    End Sub

    Public Sub RenderImage(renderInfo As ImageRenderInfo) Implements IRenderListener.RenderImage
    End Sub

    Function expandRectangleCoordinates(rectangle As IList(Of Single)) As List(Of Single)
        If rectangle.Count < 4 Then
            Return New List(Of Single)
        End If

        Return New List(Of Single)() From
        {
            rectangle(0), rectangle(1),
            rectangle(0) + rectangle(2), rectangle(1),
            rectangle(0) + rectangle(2), rectangle(1) + rectangle(3),
            rectangle(0), rectangle(1) + rectangle(3)
        }
    End Function

    Function transform(ctm As Matrix, coordinates As IList(Of Single)) As List(Of Single)
        Dim result As List(Of Single) = New List(Of Single)
        If Not coordinates Is Nothing Then
            For i = 0 To coordinates.Count - 1 Step 2
                Dim vector As Vector = New Vector(coordinates(i), coordinates(i + 1), 1)
                vector = vector.Cross(ctm)
                result.Add(vector(Vector.I1))
                result.Add(vector(Vector.I2))
            Next
        End If
        Return result
    End Function

    Public Function ToString(coordinates As IList(Of Single)) As String
        Dim result As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        result.Append("[ ")
        For i = 0 To coordinates.Count - 1
            result.Append(coordinates(i))
            result.Append(" ")
        Next
        result.Append("]")
        Return result.ToString()
    End Function

    Public Function ToString(baseColor As BaseColor) As String
        If (baseColor Is Nothing) Then
            Return "DEFAULT"
        End If
        Return String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", baseColor.R, baseColor.G, baseColor.B)
    End Function

    Function getGraphicsState(renderInfo As PathPaintingRenderInfo) As GraphicsState
        Dim gsField As Reflection.FieldInfo = GetType(PathPaintingRenderInfo).GetField("gs", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
        Return CType(gsField.GetValue(renderInfo), GraphicsState)
    End Function

    Dim pathInfos As List(Of PathConstructionRenderInfo) = New List(Of PathConstructionRenderInfo)
End Class
```

which used like this

```
Using pdfReader As New PdfReader("test.pdf")
    Dim extRenderListener As IExtRenderListener = New VectorParser

    For page = 1 To pdfReader.NumberOfPages
        Console.Write(vbCrLf + "Page {0}" + vbCrLf + "====" + vbCrLf, page)
        Dim parser As PdfReaderContentParser = New PdfReaderContentParser(pdfReader)
        parser.ProcessContent(page, extRenderListener)
    Next
End Using
```

for your shared document returns

```
Page 1
====
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 277,359 434,2797 ] line to [ 311,5242 434,2797 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 277,3591 434,2797 ] line to [ 315,0443 424,1336 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 304,2772 425,376 ] line to [ 304,4842 426,6183 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 304,6913 426,2042 ] line to [ 310,075 425,376 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 304,6913 426,8254 ] line to [ 307,5902 425,9972 ] 
FILL (0,0,255) the path move to [ 303,656 425,3759 ] line to [ 303,656 425,3759 ] line to [ 306,1407 425,1689 ] line to [ 306,1407 425,1689 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 303,656 425,376 ] line to [ 303,656 425,376 ] line to [ 306,1407 425,1689 ] line to [ 306,1407 425,1689 ] close [ ] 
FILL (0,0,255) the path move to [ 306,969 424,9618 ] line to [ 306,969 424,9618 ] line to [ 309,4538 424,7548 ] line to [ 309,4538 424,7548 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 306,969 424,9619 ] line to [ 306,969 424,9619 ] line to [ 309,4538 424,7548 ] line to [ 309,4538 424,7548 ] close [ ] 
FILL (0,0,255) the path move to [ 309,8679 424,9618 ] line to [ 309,8679 424,9618 ] line to [ 312,3527 424,5477 ] line to [ 312,3527 424,5477 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 309,868 424,9619 ] line to [ 309,868 424,9619 ] line to [ 312,3527 424,5477 ] line to [ 312,3527 424,5477 ] close [ ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 313,1809 424,3407 ] line to [ 314,8374 424,1336 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 304,2772 425,7901 ] line to [ 309,8679 424,9619 ] line to [ 312,9738 424,7548 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 304,2772 425,9972 ] line to [ 309,8679 425,1689 ] line to [ 311,5244 424,9619 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 304,6914 426,8254 ] line to [ 315,0445 424,1336 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 311,7315 435,7292 ] line to [ 311,7315 432,8303 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 321,2564 434,2797 ] line to [ 315,4587 434,2797 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 315,4586 434,2797 ] line to [ 311,7315 434,2797 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 311,7315 434,6938 ] line to [ 317,7363 434,0727 ] line to [ 311,7315 433,6585 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 311,7315 434,4868 ] line to [ 314,8374 434,2797 ] line to [ 311,7315 434,2797 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 310,6963 436,1433 ] line to [ 317,3222 434,9009 ] line to [ 322,2917 434,2797 ] line to [ 317,3222 433,6585 ] line to [ 310,6963 432,6232 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 311,7315 435,5221 ] line to [ 317,3222 434,6938 ] line to [ 321,0493 434,2797 ] line to [ 317,3222 433,8656 ] line to [ 311,7315 433,0374 ] 
STROKE (0,0,255) the path move to [ 311,7315 435,108 ] line to [ 317,3222 434,4868 ] line to [ 319,3928 434,2797 ] line to [ 317,3222 434,2797 ] line to [ 311,7315 433,4515 ]
```

This looks like a lot of instructions for a simple arrow, but zooming into the PDF one sees that the arrow indeed is constructed of numerous small lines:

[image: Screenshot]

In particular the arrow heads look like someone created them by hand using line segments of different lengths and widths.

---

The code above essentially is a port of the anonymous `ExtRenderListener` implementation for Java and iText 5.5.x in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41751396/1729265).

It is equally simple to implement this using iText 7.

---

As an aside: Unfortunately the instructions for drawing the arrow are not specifically marked; if there are other vector graphics on the same page, you'll have to filter the results returned by the parser by some specific criteria, e.g. the color (in the case at hand pure RGB blue) or the approximate coordinate range (e.g. inside a given **x** and **y** coordinate range only).

Comment: Let me test this over the weekend. I have it integrated into my project and will see if I can pick out the north arrow with other criteria as you have mentioned.

Comment: I think this put me on the right path. The testing went well and I think Ic an pick up the north arrow based on color and if I cant find that object then a secondary text search will be done.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe they are called Graphic Markups in Acrobat

Maybe you could post an example PDF? It matters a lot.

You can get the rotation of a line annotation fairly trivially: loop the annotations on the page, see if the annotation is a line annotation, get its coordinates, and calculate the rotation relative to the horizontal axis.

Using iText that looks like this:

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUT_FILE);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader);
    PdfDictionary firstPage = pdfDocument.getFirstPage().getPdfObject();
    PdfArray annots = firstPage.getAsArray(PdfName.Annots);

    if (annots != null) {
        for (int x = 0; x < annots.size(); x++) {
            if (annots.get(x).isDictionary() && annots.getAsDictionary(x).getAsName(PdfName.Subtype) == PdfName.Line) {
                PdfArray coordinates = annots.getAsDictionary(x).getAsArray(PdfName.L);

                float x2 = coordinates.getAsNumber(0).floatValue();
                float y2 = coordinates.getAsNumber(1).floatValue();
                float x1 = coordinates.getAsNumber(2).floatValue();
                float y1 = coordinates.getAsNumber(3).floatValue();

                double deltaY = y2 - y1;
                double deltaX = x2 - x1;

                double angle = Math.atan2(deltaY , deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI;
                System.out.println(angle);

            }
        }
    }
```

If you are using iText 5 `annots` has to be obtained slightly differently, but everything else should be more or less the same. Here is how to get it in 5:

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
 PdfDictionary firstPage = reader.getPageN(1);
 PdfArray annots = firstPage.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
```

Here is my PDF:

[image]

Note that the lines are Line annotations:
[image]

And this is my output:

```
131.9086081625848
90.0
```

Which looks correct. The first line is 132 degrees relative to the horizontal axis, and the second line is 90 degrees relative to the horizontal axis.

The problem becomes much more tricky if these are not line annotations because you have to track line operations in the graphics stream like you were doing before. There are two distinct issues if this is the case:

1. You have to somehow know that a line drawn is *the* line you want.
2. You have to know the entire graphic state context (transformations and where you currently are).

Comment: I have a simple graphic and only a graphic just like you have in my test PDF. Before I move on with my testing, what version of iTextSharp are you using? I ahve 5.5.13 and it barfs on new PdfDocument(reader) with no overload to accept a reader.

Comment: Jon uses a current 7.1.x.

Comment: I upgraded from iTextSharp 5.5.13 to iText 7.1.2.0. I also uploaded a sample image.

Comment: @Jon Reilly what is the software you use to enumerate the PDF data? Is that something that is available for my use?

Comment: @mkl Is correct- I am using 7.1.3. Both iText 7 and iText 5 (Often called iTextSharp for the .NET release) are available under the AGPL license. I updated my answer to show how the difference in 5, but it is more or less the same.

Comment: After I browsed the PDF with Acrobat Pro it shows the graphics as Paths under a Form XObject. I am looking up that type right now.

Comment: @sinDizzy please share the actual pdf, not merely images of it.

Comment: @mlk Added link to my test PDF.