# How to use iText to parse paths (such as lines in the document)

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText to parse text in a PDF document, and i am using `PdfContentStreamProcessor` with a `RenderListener`. Such as:

```
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file.toURI().toURL());
  int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
  MyRenderListener listener = new MyRenderListener ();
  PdfContentStreamProcessor processor = new PdfContentStreamProcessor(listener);
  for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= numberOfPages; pageNumber++) {
     PdfDictionary pageDic = reader.getPageN(pageNumber);
     PdfDictionary resourcesDic = pageDic.getAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
     Rectangle pageSize = reader.getPageSize(pageNumber);
     listener.startPage(pageNumber, pageSize);
     processor.processContent(ContentByteUtils.getContentBytesForPage(reader, pageNumber), resourcesDic);
  }
```

I have no problem to get the text with the `renderText(TextRenderInfo)` method, but how do I parse the graphic content appart from images? For example in my case I would like to get:

- Text content which is in a box
- Horizontal lines

Comment: Instead of `RenderListener` implement `ExtRenderListener` (which extends the former). This interface also gets informed about drawn paths.

Comment: Thanks! I am in the process of using the additional methods in this interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per mkl comment, by using `ExtRenderListener` I am able to get the geometries. I used [How to extract the color of a rectangle in a PDF, with iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728853/how-to-extract-the-color-of-a-rectangle-in-a-pdf-with-itext) for reference